# Print a dynamic named range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a report that I am trying to print with a VBA script. I need to print the report on one page (portrait) and have it centered. I have the formatting down pat, but the range is causing me issues. I need to set the print range to adjust to the number of values in the named range. Right now, it will print the named range, but it will not resize or print the expanded or contracted range if there have been entries added or removed.

```
Sub PrintFailureReport()

 Sheets("Failure Report").Activate
 Range("FailReportPrintArea").Select
 ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Selection.Range("FailReportPrintArea").Address
 Application.PrintCommunication = True

 With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
      .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
      .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
      .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
      .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
'         .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
'         .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
      .PrintGridlines = False
      .CenterHorizontally = True
      .CenterVertically = True
      .Orientation = xlPortrait
      .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
      .Zoom = False
      .FitToPagesWide = 1
      .FitToPagesTall = 1
      .BlackAndWhite = True
 End With

 Range("FailReportPrintArea").PrintOut

End Sub
```

Comment: Resize the named range first?

Comment: Change the columns to the ones you require, this will name the range from A1 to The last row in Column "C",`Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Name = "FailReportPrintArea"`

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with `Application.PrintCommunication = False` not being added before you set the address

```
Sub PrintFailureReport()

 Sheets("Failure Report").Activate
 Range("FailReportPrintArea").Select
 Application.PrintCommunication = False
 ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Selection.Range("FailReportPrintArea").Address
 Application.PrintCommunication = True

 With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
      .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
      .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
      .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
      .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
'         .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
'         .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
      .PrintGridlines = False
      .CenterHorizontally = True
      .CenterVertically = True
      .Orientation = xlPortrait
      .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
      .Zoom = False
      .FitToPagesWide = 1
      .FitToPagesTall = 1
      .BlackAndWhite = True
 End With

 Range("FailReportPrintArea").PrintOut

End Sub
```